# Can someone explain me this? It's about arrays and some handling of an if statement inside of array

Tags: c++

I don't understand the part of the if statement in this piece of code.
And is it possible to write this with using if and else if?

```
int klein(int A[], int n, int& i, int X) 
{

    int j;
    int kl = -1; 
    i = -1; 

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {


    if(A[j] > X && (kl == -1 || A[j] < X)) 
      {
            i = j;                      
            kl = A[j] ;                 
        }
    }
    return kl;

}
```

Comment: What part of the if statement?

Comment: If the integer of the array ```A``` at index ```j``` is bigger than ```X``` and ```kl``` is exactly ```-1``` or ```A``` at index ```j``` is smaller than ```X```, the if statment returns true.

Comment: The if condition makes no sense.  `A[j] > X` and `A[j] < X` can't be true at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I knew that it doesn't made any sense that's why I wanted to see the explanation. Because my teacher posted this answer in an exercise and I was like tf? XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is equivalent to your code because
`if(A[j]>x)` is true, then `(A[j]<x)` is false and this makes `(kl == -1 || A[j] < X))` be equivalent to `kl == -1`

```
int klein(int A[], int n, int& i, int X) 
{

    int j;
    int kl = -1; 
    i = -1; 

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {


    if(A[j] > X && kl == -1) 
      {
            i = j;                      
            kl = A[j] ;                 
        }
    }
    return kl;

}
```

Now the `if` statement says if `A[j]>x` and in the same time `kl` value is `1` perform the code insidethe `{}`